# Vue.js - clicking on span also clicks on input. how to prevent that?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a code like this.

```
<label class="pr-container">
    Please confirm you have read and understood out 
   <span @click="openConditionsModal($event, 'terms')" class="pr-default-link">Terms & Conditions</span> and
   <span @click="openConditionsModal($event, 'policy')" class="pr-default-link">Privacy Policy</span>. 
     bla blabladasd

   <input v-model="agreed" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

When I click Terms and Condition or Privacy policy spans, what also happens is `<input v-model="agreed">` also gets marked. If clicking again, it gets unmarked. What I want is when clicking on span, checkbox and its value shouldn't change at all.

Any ideas why it happens and how to avoid that?

Comment: Do you have a "prevent default" option in that handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your spans are part of a label that's associated with an input (you placed the input inside of the label). Clicking on a label associated with an input will focus or trigger the input.

I'd recommend restructuring your html and using css to fix this. Generally this approach is more robust and accessible than applying event modifiers like `stop` and `prevent`.

Your structure could look something like this:

```html
<label for="agreed">Check here to indicate that you understand:</label>
<span>Terms & Conditions</span>
<span>Privacy Policy</span>
<input v-model="agreed" type="checkbox" id="agreed">
```

You can use CSS and a bit of restructuring to make the spans and the label all appear as one unit. Note that a screen reader will tie the label to the input so having it makes sense on its own is a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Try `.stop` or `.self` modifiers to stop the event propagation as follows :

```
 <span @click.stop="openConditionsModal($event, 'terms')" ...
```

or

```
  <span @click.self="openConditionsModal($event, 'terms')" ...
```

learn more about [`event modifiers`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)

Comment: it didn't work as event propagation is children-parent connection. span and that checkbox in my example both are neighbors. :D

Comment: so try `.self` modifier

Comment: still didn't work. i have no idea why. could it be because of some css stuff?

Comment: give me some some time to reproduce the problem in codepen

Comment: @HDallakyan answer is correct, please check this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-hn8oi)

Answer (score 2):

Try to refactor your HTML like this

```
 <div class="pr-container">
            Please confirm you have read and understood out 
                   <span @click="openConditionsModal($event, 'terms')" class="pr-default-link">Terms & Conditions</span> and
                   <span @click="openConditionsModal($event, 'policy')" class="pr-default-link">Privacy Policy</span>. 
                     bla blabladasd

                <label>
                   <input v-model="agreed" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                   <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
        </div>
```